# Is Surefire (Maven) able to run several executions with different versions of dependencies? If yes, how?

Tags: maven, dependencies, execution, surefire

I wonder if it's possible to have the Maven Surefire plugin running several times (several executions) with different different versions of dependencies ?

This could be convenient for example to ensure that your code is still compatible with previous versions of project's dependencies.

I manage at least to run 2 executions of surefire :

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test-default-deps</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-anotherversion-deps</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports-anotherversion-deps</reportsDirectory>
              <dependencies>

                <!-- Version different of the default for the project -->
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.dep.groupid</groupId>
                  <artifactId>dep-artifact</artifactId>
                  <version>anotherversion</version>
                </dependency>

              </dependencies>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

But this different version is not taken into account during the 2nd execution.
Am I trying to do something unfeasible or am I doing in the wrong way ?
Is there another plugin that could be helpful for this purpose ?

Comment: You could have surefire run with a different set of dependencies in a separate profile.

Comment: The thing is that I want to test that my code is still backward-compatible with an older version of the dependency which does not contain a new class. At runtime, this lead to a ClassNotFoundException. I would like to reproduce the problem with a unit-test before fixing it. And, tell me if I'm wrong but, if in another profile I declare different dependencies, it has to be done at the main level not at surefire-plugin level. So this impacts as well compilation, not only the runtime of surefire. Therefore, the code using the dependency won't compile anymore, far before running surefire.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible since Surefire 3.2 as it supports `additionalClasspathDependencies` and `classpathDependencyExclude` which allow modifying the test class path. Here is an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>2.0</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>test</phase>
           <configuration>
              <reportNameSuffix>2.0</reportNameSuffix>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                 <classpathDependencyExclude>groupId:artifactId</classpathDependencyExclude>
                 <!-- Add any transitives here -->
              </classpathDependencyExcludes>
              <additionalClasspathDependencies>
                 <additionalClasspathDependency>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                 </additionalClasspathDependency>
              </additionalClasspathDependencies>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
           <id>3.0</id>
           <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>test</phase>
           <configuration>
              <reportNameSuffix>3.0</reportNameSuffix>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                 <classpathDependencyExclude>groupId:artifactId</classpathDependencyExclude>
                 <!-- Add any transitives here -->
              </classpathDependencyExcludes>
              <additionalClasspathDependencies>
                 <additionalClasspathDependency>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                 </additionalClasspathDependency>
              </additionalClasspathDependencies>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
```